# Synchronization between Semaphore/Mutex and Printf

Tags: c, printf, mutex, semaphore, binary-semaphore

I'm working on an exercise (see **bold text** below) on semaphores and synchronization for my Operative System course. The text of the exercise is this:

***Pthread semaphores and mutexes***

> The C program gen_binary_numbers.c receives on the command line an integer n, and uses recursion to generate and display all binary numbers of n bits.**Transform the recursive program into a concurrent one, replacing the recursive procedure with the generation of an appropriate number of processes that display the binary numbers (in any order).**

This is my code, actually:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int num, r, c;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
void *genBin(void *arg);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stdout, "\nUSAGE: %s <n>\n\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int i;
  num = atoi(argv[1]);
  c = num;
  r = 2;
  for (i=1; i<num; i++) {
    r=r*2;
  }

  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
  pthread_t* p;
  p = malloc(r*sizeof(pthread_t));

  for (i=0;i<r;i++) {
    if (pthread_create(&p[i], NULL, genBin, &i)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void *genBin (void *arg) {
  int x;
  int i=0;
  x = *((int*)arg);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

  while (i<num) {
    if(x!=0) {
      fprintf(stdout, "%d", x%2);
    }
    else {
      fprintf(stdout, "0");
    }
    i++;
    x/=2;
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "\n");
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I think that the code should return the right solution, but sometimes the output doesn't return the correct number.

**Example of correct output:**

```
./genBin 3
100
101
010
110
001
011
111
000
```

**Example of wrong output (because of duplicates):**

```
./genBin 3
110
110
110
001
011
111
111
000
```

I think that the problem is in the synchronization between the mutex and the printf.
Is there an alternative solution to avoid confusing results?

Comment: The problem statement says you are to create multiple *processes*, but your program instead creates *threads*.  These are not the same thing, and although there are similar considerations for the two, the details differ.

Comment: Also, you're a bit vague about the nature of the failure behavior.  An example of the erroneous output and an explanation of why it is erroneous would be appropriate.

Comment: You're right, but I forgot to tell you that the title of the lab is **Pthread semaphores and mutexes**. So, I think that I have to use pthreads. I'll correct it in the text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains a race condition.  In main, you pass the address of your iteration variable, `i`, as the thread function's argument.  Each new thread then races with the main thread to read the value of `i` (via the provided pointer) before the main thread increments it.  One way you could address that problem would be to use a semaphore to make the main thread wait after creating each thread until that thread has dereferenced its argument.

Also, I don't think you need to use a mutex in `genBin()`.  The only shared data it accesses is `stdout`, via `fprintf()`, and that function operates as if it locks an exclusive lock associated with the specified stream.  Moreover, with the mutex you get essentially no actual concurrency because each thread holds the mutex locked for almost the complete duration of its execution.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the part with race condition and I moved the lock/unlock of the mutex in order to surround only the part of printf.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part:

```
  for (i=0;i<r;i++) {
    if (pthread_create(&p[i], NULL, genBin, &i)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
```

There's [*data race*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-0619/geojs/index.html) because you are passing the address of `i` to all threads. You could use an temp array to pass the individual number to each thread.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone! You solved my problem. This is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int num, r, c;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
void *genBin(void *arg);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stdout, "\nUSAGE: %s <n>\n\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int i;
  int *temp;
  num = atoi(argv[1]);
  c = num;
  r = 2;
  for (i=1; i<num; i++) {
    r=r*2;
  }

  temp = malloc(r*sizeof(int));
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
  pthread_t* p;
  p = malloc(r*sizeof(pthread_t));

  for (i=0;i<r;i++) {
    temp[i] = i;  
  }

  for (i=0;i<r;i++) {
    if (pthread_create(&p[i], NULL, genBin, &temp[i])) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
  }

  for (i=0;i<r;i++) {
    if (pthread_join(p[i], NULL)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  free(temp);
  free(p);
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void *genBin (void *arg) {
  int x;
  int i=0;
  int *v;
  v = malloc(num*sizeof(int));
  x = *((int*)arg);

  for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
    v[i] = x%2;
    x/=2;
  }

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%d", v[i]);
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "\n");
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  free(v);
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Note that there are memory leaks (you are not free()'ing anything). This is not an issue on most modern operating systems, as memory would be reclaimed on exit. Just something to be aware of. Also, the lock is not needed since there's no shared resource involved in your code. The purpose of it seems to be to avoid interleaved output. But you can fix by passing the result back to main and printing them all at the end.

Comment: I always forget to do free(), I'll correct it in the code soon, thanks. I have to use mutex in this exercise, but thanks for the hint!

Comment: The pthread_mutex_destroy() and free() calls you just added are problematic. If main thread exits *before* the other threads, then `temp[x]` might be invalid. SImilarly, the mutex might still be in use by other threads when main destroys it. One way is to exit the main thread as the last i.e. instead of calling pthread_exit in main, you can do pthread_join in a loop and then free up resources.
Or, you could just take out these free'ing too as these leaks won't be a problem in pretty much all uses of your code.

Comment: If sightly changed there is not need for a mutex at all.